# Cannot find '.component' and '.service' module exception on "npm start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Am just taking baby steps in Angular-2, have gone through [5-min quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and [ScothIO example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-your-first-angular-2-components). Am trying an example with Components and Services, i cant even bring up my application when i fire `npm start` command.

I get following error :

```
app/app.ts(5,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '/app/family.component'.
app/app.ts(6,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '/app/family.service'.
app/family.component.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/family.service'.
```

I understand the fact that Angular / TypeScript is unable to find `family.component` and `family.service` when its trying to compile but all the Import paths seem to be correct for me as it worked all fine in the [5-min quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) example when tried.

Here is the [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z9qP799LLjZLLhFnshhI?p=preview) which has all code files

Please help me out in rectifying this Compile exception.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PMt6BvYMw69BSvocvOmT?p=preview

Comment: @micronyks : can u plz tell what changes have u done in plunker link u provided ?  I see all files being same except few changes in systemjs.config.js

Comment: Yes I changed `systemjs.config.js`.

Comment: @micronyks no luck sir. I assumed the only change in `systemjs.config.js` was **'app':{ main: 'app.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },** where i had used `.js` earlier. If there r any more changes please let me know.

Comment: What are doing? are you playing with ES6/6 or Typescript?

Comment: @micronyks - Typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the path in your app.ts is incorrect for family.component and family.service...

just change the path from app/family.component to just ./family.component

> changes:-
>
> app/family.component ==>  ./family.component
>
> app/family.service ==>  ./family.service

this will solve your problem :)